# double regroup in django template

Tags: django, templates, django-templates

i have some output from a django view that requires some sorting. i'm hoping i can do this in the template rather in in code:

basically, i need to represent a node/edge graph; however, there may be many edges between two nodes (directed) - therefore i want to create unique id's between them so that my json doesn't get overwritten ('measurement1' and 'measurement2'):

```
nodes: { 
  nodeA: {},
  nodeB: {}
},
edges: {
  nodeA: { 
    nodeB: { 
      measurement1: {},
      measurement2: {}
    }
  }
}
```

so my model is basically like this:

```
class Measurement( models.Model ):
  service = models.ForeignKey( Service, db_index=True )
  source_node = models.ForeignKey( Node, related_name='source' )
  target_node = models.ForeignKey( Node, related_name='target' )
```

the problem is that my template currently looks like this (which will overwrite the json :

```
"nodes": <blah>
"edges": {
  {% regroup measurements by source_node_id as source_list %}
  {% for source in source_list %}
  "{{ source.grouper }}": {
    {% for item in source.list %}
      "{{ item.target_node_id }}": { 
        "id": "{{ item.id }}",
        "service_type": "{{ item.service.service_type|lower }}" }{% if not forloop.last %},{% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  }{% if not forloop.last %},{% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
}
```

which in term gives something like:

```
edges: {
  nodeA: {
    nodeB: {
      id: measurement1,
      service_type: service1
    },
    nodeB: {
      id: measurement2,
      service_type: service2
    }
}
```

so basically, i need a nested regroup statement within the `for item in source.list` for just the measurements that match that particular source and target nodes within that loop; but i can't seem to get it to work. any suggestions?

Comment: Is this JSON enclosed inside other HTML or off by itself?

Comment: its a restful-ish interface, so its by itself.

Comment: You would probably be better off not using the templates and doing it through the code.  But that's not an answer to your specific question.

Comment: agreed, but i was hoping that there would be an 'easier' way... the issue of doing it in code would be that i would have to remap/copy all the data (eg with Service). cheers,

Answer (score 0):

I would be inclined to do it without using regroup at all. Keeping in mind that regroup requires your list to be ordered to begin with, I assume that your list is already ordered at both levels. Given that, you could do something like the following using ifchanged to keep track of whether the source and/or target node has changed since the previous loop iteration. You'll probably want to trim some whitespace in order to produce prettier output:

```
edges: {
{% for meas in measurements %}
  {% ifchanged meas.source_node_id %}
    {% if not forloop.first %}
        }
      },
    {% endif %}
    {{ meas.source_node_id }}: {
      {{ meas.target_node_id }}: {
  {% else %}
    {% ifchanged meas.target_node_id %}
      },
      {{ meas.target_node_id }}: {
    {% else %}
      ,
    {% endifchanged %}
  {% endifchanged %}
  measurement{{ meas.id }}: { }
  {% if forloop.last %}
    }
  }
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
}
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure that the nested `ifchanged` will work right. I wonder whether `ifchanged` boils down to a test of whether the value changed since the last time the node was rendered, rather than since the last loop iteration. The edge case to test is to verify that this renders properly if the _last_ target node of a given source node is identical to the _second_ target node of the next source node in the list. If the nested `ifchanged` is rendered, then all is well. If not, it may be a bit trickier to get this right.

Comment: Thinking about it some more, if the nested `ifchanged` proves a problem, you could combine the `regroup` and `ifchanged` approaches -- use the `regroup` as you are currently, and use the `ifchanged` approach for the inner loop.